# Jade behaviours scheduling

Tags: java, agents-jade, multi-agent

I'm studying Jade and I know that the behaviours scheduling is **not preemptive**, but what I have not understood is if every agent's behaviour must wait for the conclusion of the `done()` method of the previous behaviour?

I'm asking because if I have a class that extends `TickerBehaviour` and I set a timer, what if another behaviour action() method takes a lot of time and overtakes the `TickerBehaviour` class timer?

This is an example of a class that extends `TickerBehaviour`:

```
public class MyTicker extends TickerBehaviour{


    public MyTicker(Agent a, long period)
    {
        super(a, period);

    }

    protected void onTick()
    {

        System.out.println(this.myAgent.getLocalName() + ": ticker --- " + pastMillisec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following example will help you better understand behaviour scheduling in Jade.

It simply schedules 2 `TickerBehaviour` Behaviours, each having the same class timer (3000ms or 3 seconds). The difference is that the second `TickerBehaviour` Behaviour, contains a `Thread.sleep(8000);`, which is a classic trick to emulate computational loads. So, the second behaviour, is going to sleep agent's thread for 8 seconds, which is almost 2.66 times bigger that the tick timer.

Since in Jade, behaviour scheduling is not preemptive(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking) as you said, this means that the first behaviour added to the scheduler will be executed and when the scheduler is done with the behaviour (or one of the scenarios mentioned in the wiki link mentioned above happens), it is going to schedule the next one contained in the list of behaviours.

For the `TickerBehaviour` problem, this means that when the scheduler switches to the second `TickerBehaviour`, it's going to be busy for 8000ms. Meanwhile, the 1st `TickerBehaviour` will have triggered, so it will be added to the list of behaviours. Thus, when the scheduler have finished with the "time consuming behaviour", is going to schedule the next one available in the list and so on and so forth.

```
public class Agent1 extends Agent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void setup() {

        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - Agent Behaviours Started");

        addBehaviour(new TickerBehaviour(this, 3000) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            // how many times this behaviour triggered
            int count = 0;

            @Override
            protected void onTick() {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - TickerBehaviour1, period: 3000ms, count: " + count);
                count++;

            }
        });

        addBehaviour(new TickerBehaviour(this, 3000) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            // how many times this behaviour triggered
            int count = 0;

            @Override
            protected void onTick() {

                // this behaviour puts the agent's thread to sleep for 8 seconds
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(8000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - TickerBehaviour2, period: 3000ms, count: " + count);
                count++;

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Executing the above Agent, results the following stdout:

```
2018-03-11T13:12:04.116 - Agent Behaviours Started
2018-03-11T13:12:07.120 - TickerBehaviour1, period: 3000ms, count: 0
2018-03-11T13:12:15.121 - TickerBehaviour2, period: 3000ms, count: 0
2018-03-11T13:12:15.122 - TickerBehaviour1, period: 3000ms, count: 1
2018-03-11T13:12:26.122 - TickerBehaviour2, period: 3000ms, count: 1
2018-03-11T13:12:26.122 - TickerBehaviour1, period: 3000ms, count: 2
2018-03-11T13:12:37.124 - TickerBehaviour2, period: 3000ms, count: 2
2018-03-11T13:12:37.124 - TickerBehaviour1, period: 3000ms, count: 3
2018-03-11T13:12:48.125 - TickerBehaviour2, period: 3000ms, count: 3
2018-03-11T13:12:48.126 - TickerBehaviour1, period: 3000ms, count: 4
2018-03-11T13:12:59.126 - TickerBehaviour2, period: 3000ms, count: 4
2018-03-11T13:12:59.126 - TickerBehaviour1, period: 3000ms, count: 5
2018-03-11T13:13:10.128 - TickerBehaviour2, period: 3000ms, count: 5
```

Here, the 2 `TickerBehaviour` behaviours are scheduled at 13:12:04(hours:minutes:seconds). The first behaviour finishes 3 seconds later as expected, but the second one does not. It finishes after 3seconds(behaviour timer) + 8seconds(the load) = 11seconds from when it was scheduled. Meanwhile, the 1st isn't executed again after 3 seconds, but it waits for the 2nd to finish.

tl;dr : The scheduling time and the execution time, are two different things.

Hope it helps